# Is there any possible to dynamic change the IP for each request in Fiddler or mitmdump?

Tags: python, web-crawler, ip, fiddler

I have tried to search the API from the Fiddler Script documentation, but I have found nothing(It may be due to that I am not familiar with `JScript.NET`).

And I still tried to use `flow.live.change_upstream_proxy_server(proxy)` (I found it on Google). I was following the answer to start my python script with command: `mitmdump --mode upstream:http://default-upstream-proxy.local:8080/ -s .\test_mitmdump.py`. However it only caught data package, still did't work.

I have searched Google and still could't work it out.

There is a apart of my python script:

```py
    def request(flow: http.HTTPFlow) -> None:
        if flow.live:
            ip = random_IP()        # random choose an IP from local file
            proxy = ip
            flow.live.change_upstream_proxy_server(proxy)
```

Comment: Via Fiddler script you can individually modify every request and/or response you want: https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/knowledgebase/fiddlerscript/modifyrequestorresponse

Comment: I have seen that before，and I've tried like this under the OnBeforeRequest():
`    if (oSession.host=="https://httpbin.org:8888"){
            oSession.host="1.20.99.83:40774";
        }`
but it didn't work.
It there any wrong,or  maybe I use the wrong API?